# How can I use Java Web Start using java 14?

Tags: java

the version of java i'm using is 14.0.1. and the book I'm using to study is using java 8.
I'd like to use Java Web Start, and the instructions in the book that I'm using is I have to compile first with this command in CLI:

```
javac -classpath .:jdk/jre/lib/javaws.jar webstart/*.java
```

but I can't find javaws.jar nor the jre folder in the jdk-14.0.1 folder. Do I have to change the version of java that I'm using to use JavaWS or there's a way to use JavaWS in java 14?

Answer (score 0):

Java WebStart is not supported in modern versions of Java, but is still quite useful.

I would suggest you switch to Java 8 while you study, which should allow you to do the exercises.  You can then update your knowledge later when you are more familiar with the platform.